# Table pagination, content is not showing in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli, pagination

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r179H.png)The problem is the content of my table is not showing. It is counting and show the the equal row from my database but no content is showing. Can you please help me?

**index.php**

```
<?php  
include('db.php');

$limit = 2;  
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales_order ORDER BY `so_id` ASC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
?>  
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
<thead>  
<tr>  
<th>title</th>  
<th>body</th>  
</tr>  
<thead>  
<tbody>  
<?php  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {  
?>  
            <tr>  
            <td><? echo $row["so_customer"]; ?></td>  
            <td><? echo $row["so_address"]; ?></td>  
            </tr>  
<?php  
};  
?>  
</tbody>  
</table>  
<?php  
$sql = "SELECT COUNT('so_id') FROM sales_order";  
$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);  
$total_records = $row[0];  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
$pagLink = "<div class='pagination'>";  
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
             $pagLink .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";  
};  
echo $pagLink . "</div>";  ?>
```

Comment: It's not causing your problem but `so_id` should not be enclosed in single quotes in your queries, it should either be in backticks (`\``) or no quotes at all.

Comment: I`ve changed it, but nothing happened

Comment: Have you checked for an error from your query? What happens if you change `$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` to `$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`? Also you need to change those quotes on both queries.

Comment: That isn't the only thing wrong, but these also `COUNT('so_id')`, remove those or use ticks.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner what do you mean? Sorry im just new to this.

Comment: Are you sure the fields are called `so_customer` and `so_address`?

Comment: @Nick yes, What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Well you are getting two rows in your table so it is returning two rows of data from the database and the values in `$row` would appear to be empty. Can you try `var_dump($row);` in the loop?

Comment: It shows my data but not inside the table.

Comment: ...probably because short tags are not enabled. Your code works fine for me, after debugging a few lines. Given you removed the regular quotes around `COUNT()`. You're going to get some undefined index notices also, so enable error reporting and check for errors on the query as previously stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things wrong left over from your edited question earlier, most particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53017985/2) where you changed the single quotes from `ORDER BY 'so_id'` to using backticks:

```
ORDER BY `so_id`
```

More on what are called "Identifier Qualifiers" can be seen in the following reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Then about `<? echo`. Those are what are called [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) and if they're unabled, you need to change them to `<?php echo` or `<?=` which also does the same.

Then your quotes in `COUNT('so_id')`. Either remove them or replace them with backticks.

```
COUNT(`so_id`)
```

Finally; you're going to receive undefined index notices for these as soon as the page is loaded:

```
<td><? echo $row["so_customer"]; ?></td>  
<td><? echo $row["so_address"]; ?></td>
```

Therefore and to avoid / fix those errors, replace them with the following:

```
<td><?php if(isset($row['so_customer'])){ echo $row["so_customer"]; } ?></td>  
<td><?php if(!empty($row['so_address'])){ echo $row["so_address"]; }?></td>
```

Enabling error reporting for the PHP and error handling for the MySQL, would have been of help during development/debugging.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php